# SailsJS Custom API Hook - Subdomain

Tags: javascript, regex, amazon-web-services, sails.js

I recently tried to deploy a SailsJS app to an AWS environment, and thus I set up the relevant staging and production env files.

One persistent issue I had however was when I ran the app with:

```
sails lift --staging
```

I noticed I either got recurring redirects or it was not reachable at all.

After some further digging, I happened to come across this code located in the `api/hooks/custom/index.js` file:

```
// Next, if we're running in our actual "production" or "staging" Sails
// environment, check if this is a GET request via some other subdomain,
// for example something like `webhooks.` or `click.`.  If so, we'll
// automatically go ahead and redirect to the corresponding path under
// our base URL, which is environment-specific.
// > Note that we DO NOT redirect virtual socket requests and we DO NOT
// > redirect non-GET requests (because it can confuse some 3rd party
// > platforms that send webhook requests.)
var configuredBaseSubdomain;
try {
    configuredBaseSubdomain = url.parse(sails.config.custom.baseUrl).host.match(/^([^\.]+)\./)[1];
} catch (unusedErr) { /*…*/}
if ((sails.config.environment === 'staging' || sails.config.environment === 'production') && !req.isSocket && req.method === 'GET' && req.subdomains[0] !== configuredBaseSubdomain) {
    sails.log.info('Redirecting GET request from `'+req.subdomains[0]+'.` subdomain...');
    return res.redirect(sails.config.custom.baseUrl+req.url);
}//•
```

I tried to ask around on the IRC channels and Gitter.im links, but my queries 'got lost in the noise' per-say, so thought I'd just ask here and leave it up for discussion. Is there not a better way to handle this?

Deploying on an AWS environment with a URL http://ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.locale-x.compute.amazonaws.com or just accessing via an IP address are both caught by the regex used:

```
/^([^\.]+)\./
```

Which makes deploying quite hard unless the app is in the root route (haha) of a site. Is there not another way to handle this?

For now, I've had to comment it out just so my staged app is usable/testable. I also realise that this might have been rendered via a parameter passed when initially creating my project via the [sails-generate](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-generate) project, but I haven't tracked it down yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i was running into the same issue. Seems we both used the generator at a time that resulted in the code including the regex above. It is now changed with this commit and as soon as you change the code in your repo to the below it actually works again!

https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-generate/commit/76e2096d8173d474b6152a67ff4cfa08c38e6460

Comment: Sweet, nice find :) maybe someone heard our outcries